# Stopwatch messed up after switching back from another tab

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, nsdate, nstimer, uitabbar

I have a stopwatch that is working just fine on its own, but when I switch back from another view from the tab bar, the stopwatch does some weird things (tapping the back button on the navigation view works fine).

1. The stopwatch label is hidden when the user switches back from the other tab, even though it should be visible when showing the view.
2. If the stopwatch is running when the user taps on the other tab and taps on the stopwatch tab again, the stopwatch goes to -31:-23.-64, and the stop button (which should reset the timer and show the start button) won't do anything when tapped.
3. If the stopwatch is not running when the user taps on the other tab and taps on the stopwatch tab again, the stopwatch will start normally, but the stop button is not showing when the user taps the start button.

Here is my code:

.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnStart;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnStop;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimer;
    NSTimer *stopWatchTimer;
    NSDate *stopDate;
    NSDate *startDate;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimer;

- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnStop:(id)sender;
```

.m:

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    lblTimer.text = timeString;
}

- (IBAction)buttonStart:(id)sender {

    startDate = [NSDate date];

    // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 1ms
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    btnStop.hidden = NO;
    btnStart.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)buttonStop:(id)sender {

    [self updateTimer];
    btnStop.hidden = YES;
    btnStart.hidden = NO;

    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this, or if anything else is needed.

Comment: Are you doing anything in the viewwillAppear method of stopwatch's viewController?

Comment: no, there's nothing in the `viewDidAppear` either, should there be?

Comment: No what I am saying is that your issue could be because of some property chnage in viewwillappear. Since this function is always called when you change your tab

Comment: You should post more code. The picture isn't clear enough. By the way you're creating 100 `NSDateFormatter`s per second, well you're trying to anyway, that's terrible! Even a very performant game only redraws at about 60fps, why in the world would you need 100fps? But in any case more code would help us find your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like startDate is messed up.  The `init` is being called.  It should probably just be `[NSDate date]`.

As for the view not appearing... after calculating the date, `timer.text` is being set to something.  What is timer?  Are you sure that shouldn't be `timer.title`?  And after you do that, you may need to `[timer setNeedsDisplay]` to make sure the text is updated on the control if that's what you want.

If the text is still messed up, try to update less often. Maybe every tenth second and see if the text behaves better.

Comment: Ok, I just updated my code to reflect that `timer` is a label and added the .h file to show what my other objects are. I have also changed `[[NSDate date] init]` to just `[NSDate date]` and tested that along with `[lblTimer setNeedsDisplay]` and updating the timer less often, but nothing different happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just figured out the problem... I was setting one-too-many things to nil in the `viewWillDisappear` method. Thanks for your help though.